# Spike in DynamicSharedMemoryControlLock Postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

Been seeing spike in DB connection usage and our RDS metrics reported a major spike in `DynamicSharedMemoryControlLock` at the same time.

There are regular spikes in DB connections but it does not always result in increase of `DynamicSharedMemoryControlLock`.

Reading PG docs and other message boards does not shed any light on what could be causing these locks to spike.

Comment: Is it similar to BUG #15585: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/31541555076899@sas1-b3ec53dbc12b.qloud-c.yandex.net ?

If you think this a bug you should contact pgsql-bugs mailing list.

Comment: What does Amazon RDS support say ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a Postgres bug in pg11. More details here: https://marc.info/?l=pgsql-bugs&m=155507635206679&w=2